# Adjacency matrix to array for multiplication purposes

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, matrix, adjacency-matrix

I am having difficulties with matrices multiplication. When I get the adjacency matrix for a graph using `get_adjacency()` this produces a matrix but what I want is an array so that I can use the `numpy.dot()` for multiplication. How can I transform the squared adjacency matrix to an array?
this is the error I get when I multiply the matrix by an array of ones:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/Michael/Desktop/ScaleFreeNetEigenvecCentraliza.py", line 19, in <module>
    x=dot(M,x)
ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.
```

Thank you

Comment: You need to describe the matrix and situation in more detail.  An `np.matrix` can do a `dot` product - that is its normal `*` multiplication.  But I suspect more confusion than that.

Comment: the matrix is the one supplied by graph, i.e. g.get_adjacency() which is the adjacency matrix of the graph.   [link](http://example.com) _italic_ **bold** `code`